# This function should delete the previous embed sent to a channel, and then send the new embed, but it gives me an error

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a channel where I only want 1 embed. However, this embed needs to be updated every 10 seconds, so the only way is by deleting the previous embed and then send the new one. However, I run into an error and I am pretty sure it's because of the `await message.delete()`

This is the code:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def update_embed():
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Title",description="Description")
    embed_channel = client.get_channel(123456789123456789)
    await message.delete()
    await embed_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The error:

```
undefined name 'message'
```

Comment: The error is explicit : you use a variable `message` but it is defined nowhere. Did you wrote that code yourself ?

Comment: at start channel is empty - so how do you want to delete previous message if channel is empty?

Comment: Let's consider there is already 1 message on that channel

Comment: in this situation this message has to be send with `message = await embed_channel.send(embed=embed)` and it has to be global variable `global message`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it.

First: if you send message then you get value which you have to assign to variable - and this value allow you to access this message later

```
message = await embed_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

but you have to assign it to global variable to keep it when it exits this function.

```
global message

message = await embed_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

But now problem is at start when channel is empty and there is no message to delete.

You have to first assign some default value - ie. `None` - and check if you want to delete real message or default value - `if message is not None:`

```
# global variable (created outside functions) with default value `None`
message = None

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def update_embed():
    global message  # inform function that it has to assign to global variable `message` 
                    # instead of creating local variable `message`

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Title",description="Description")
    embed_channel = client.get_channel(123456789123456789)

    if message is not None:
        await message.delete()

    message = await embed_channel.send(embed=embed)
```